# Insert spaces in specific field

Tags: awk, sed

How can I insert space between strings in field 3 only in a file.
I can use command  `sed "s// /g"` but this will do globally in a file. How can I do only for column 3.

Say input is as

```
A  seq      A1A2
B  comb   A1A2A3
```

I want output as

```
A  seq      A1 A2
B  comb   A1 A2 A3
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk '{gsub(/../,"& ",$3);sub(/ +$/,"",$3)} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: @NEHA CHOUDHARY, could you please do let me know if my solution has worked fine for you? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to insert a whitespace in the "gap" between digit and alphabet in the 3rd column, with `GNU awk`:

```
awk '{$3 = gensub("([[:digit:]])([[:alpha:]])", "\\1 \\2", "g", $3)} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have only three fields on all lines

```
awk '{printf($1 " " $2 " ");  n=split($3,a,""); for(i=1; i <= n; i++) printf(a[i] " "); printf("\n")}' file
```

if you have more than 3 fields and want to print remaining fields after splitting 3rd field, along with first 2 fields:

```
awk '{printf($1 " " $2 " ");  n=split($3,a,"");for(i=1; i <= n; i++) printf(a[i] " "); $1="";$2="";$3="";print($0); printf("\n")}' file
```